# Why does terminate() recieve 'permission denied' when I try and end my Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run TCPDump as a subprocess with Python using the code below but p.terminate() fails to end the process and the only way I am able to kill it is with 'sudo kill (pid)' from the cli.

Here's the code I'm trying to run...

```
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime


def TCPDump():
    path_to_output_file = '/home/user/output.txt'
    myoutput = open(path_to_output_file, 'w+')
    func_name = "AutoTCPDump"

    print(func_name + "start")
    print(func_name + "about to create capture")
    p = subprocess.Popen(["tcpdump",
                          "-U",
                          "-i", "enp0s8",
                          "-w", "/home/user/Test.pcap"],
                         stdout=myoutput, stderr=myoutput, universal_newlines=True)

    time.sleep(10)
    print("end")
    p.terminate()

TCPDump()
```

Here's the error I receive...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TCPDump2.py", line 24, in <module>
    TCPDump()
  File "TCPDump2.py", line 20, in TCPDump
    p.terminate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1605, in terminate
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1600, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The code is running on Ubuntu 18.0.04 Desktop and I've modified system permissions to allow TCPDump to run as the standard user and this works OK interactively from the cli.

Any help/advice greatly appreciated.
Thanks

An update on this, looking in syslog it appears apparmour has some issues here...

```
Jul 25 10:05:11 matt-VirtualBox kernel: [ 2412.365557] audit: type=1400 audit(1595667911.307:279): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" name="/dev/pts/2" pid=14069 comm="tcpdump" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

Jul 25 10:05:11 matt-VirtualBox kernel: [ 2412.365560] audit: type=1400 audit(1595667911.307:280): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" name="/dev/pts/2" pid=14069 comm="tcpdump" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

Jul 25 10:05:11 matt-VirtualBox kernel: [ 2412.365561] audit: type=1400 audit(1595667911.307:281): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" name="/dev/pts/2" pid=14069 comm="tcpdump" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

Jul 25 10:05:11 matt-VirtualBox kernel: [ 2412.365563] audit: type=1400 audit(1595667911.307:282): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" name="/dev/pts/2" pid=14069 comm="tcpdump" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

Jul 25 10:05:21 matt-VirtualBox kernel: [ 2422.379112] audit: type=1400 audit(1595667921.318:283): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=14068 comm="python3" requested_mask="receive" denied_mask="receive" signal=term peer="snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community"
```

I'm not very familiar with reading these logs, any advice on what might be going on?

Comment: you may  try changing /home/user/Test.pcap to /tmp/Test.pcap

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - It was Apparmour blocking access to TCPdump.
Disabling the TCPDump profile in Apparmour resolved the issue